# When try to open network settings it close immediatly

Tags: networking, release-odin

i'm a begginer of linux.
I've install the stable elementaryOS 6 Odin release:
[image: build-info]
When I try to open "network settings" from the tool on the sidebar or from the settings menu it always appear then close immediatly.
see the gif below:
https://s9.gifyu.com/images/network_settings_problem.gif

I don't know how to resolve it.

**Update 09/02/2021**
As @Goran suggest I've tried to launch `sudo io.elementary.switchboard` and then into the network settings but it close immediatly but on terminal appear this:
`(io.elementary.switchboard:2465): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 21:29:29.121: gtk_widget_realize: assertion 'widget->priv->anchored || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed`
`**`
`Gtk:ERROR:../../../../gtk/gtkwidget.c:12412:gtk_widget_real_map: assertion failed: (_gtk_widget_get_realized (widget))`
`Bail out! Gtk:ERROR:../../../../gtk/gtkwidget.c:12412:gtk_widget_real_map: assertion failed: (_gtk_widget_get_realized (widget))`

**Update 08/30/2021:**
I've tried to do a fresh install of elementary OS 6 on my laptop but seems the problem is also at the begin...
I've a *Dell Latitude E7270*, I don't know if anyone else have the same problem.
Thanks for help

**Update 08/26/2021:**
I take the last row of syslog in the last 5 mins when i try to open the network menu:
`Aug 26 23:02:45 elementaryPC systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Run anacron jobs being skipped.`
`Aug 26 23:05:08 elementaryPC gala[1690]: clutter_actor_remove_child: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_ACTOR (child)' failed`
`Aug 26 23:05:08 elementaryPC gala[1690]: invalid (NULL) pointer instance`
`Aug 26 23:05:08 elementaryPC gala[1690]: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed`
`Aug 26 23:05:08 elementaryPC io.elementary.wingpanel.desktop[3630]: **`
`Aug 26 23:05:08 elementaryPC io.elementary.wingpanel.desktop[3630]: Gtk:ERROR:../../../../gtk/gtkwidget.c:12412:gtk_widget_real_map: assertion failed: (_gtk_widget_get_realized (widget))`
`Aug 26 23:05:08 elementaryPC io.elementary.wingpanel.desktop[3630]: Bail out! Gtk:ERROR:../../../../gtk/gtkwidget.c:12412:gtk_widget_real_map: assertion failed: (_gtk_widget_get_realized (widget))`
`Aug 26 23:05:08 elementaryPC io.elementary.s[3630]: gtk_widget_realize: assertion 'widget->priv->anchored || GTK_IS_INVISIBLE (widget)' failed`

Seems there is a problem with an element named `io.elementary.wingpanel.desktop`

Comment: There may be a clue in the `/var/log/syslog` file, which often contains details about why something might have crashed. Can you take a look in that file and, if you see anything that looks like it might be related to the network settings window closing immediately, [edit] your question to include the logs? This will make it a little easier to offer some specific suggestions 

Answer (score 0):

I has similar issue with the power settings, it would hang anytime I tried to get into the subsection from the config panel (switchboard)

What worked for me was running switchboard as root from the terminal with `sudo io.elementary.switchboard`  and configuring it from there. You can try the same thing for the network settings.

I think there is a bug with the policykit or something related that requires elevated permissions in the switchboard (network, power, user accounts, etc)